Non available Sharepoint sites show up in powershell command
Pure cloud microsoft 365 subscription,
When runngung the command:
Get-SPOSite -limit all
shows more sites than these in sharepoint admin center either active or deletes sites. These extra sites were deleted along time ago over 90 days of the recycling.
It is solved by running a ps script to delete these extra sites.
My question is: is there any declaration or reason for that?

The reason why the PowerShell command shows more sites than those in the SharePoint admin center is that the command retrieves all SharePoint sites, including deleted ones, while the admin center only shows active or deleted sites that are still in the recycle bin. This is why you see extra sites that were deleted over 90 days ago. There is no specific declaration or reason for this behavior, it is simply how the command works.Get-SPOSiteGet-SPOSite.

Do you mean, that Get-SPOSite returns all sites, active sites, deleted sites in the recycling storage and even the permanently deleted sites
